# Memcached timeout

Tags: c, libmemcached

I found sample code about using libmemcached in C/C++. But I don't understand the meaning of two timeout:

1. memcached_timeout of memcached_behavior_set()
2. expire of memcached_set()

   `rc = memcached_behavior_set( memc_primary, MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT , memcached_timeout );`

   `rc = memcached_set( memc_primary, memcached_key_val, memcached_key_len, save_value, strlen( save_value ), expire, 0 );`

Could you please explain what they are used for?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_behavior.html)?

Comment: @unwind, Yes, But it said that **In non-blocking mode this changes the value of the timeout during socket connection in milliseconds. Specifying -1 means an infinite time‐out**. Is it timeout of socket connection? And what is meaning of `expire` in memcached_set()?